# After setTimeout, this loses context

Tags: javascript, dom-events, underscore.js

I have this self made function called `succeeder` which is supposed to try to run a function called `func` and if it fails to try and run it again after an interval.

This works great the first time and when `func` is called for the second time after `setTimeout` it fails and this seems out of context.

Can you think of anything that is not right in this snippet?

```
succeeder({
    func : function () {
        !this.dbOpen && this.init();
        return true;
    },
    context : this,
    interval : 2000,
    success : function () { return true;}
});

function succeeder(opts) {
    function run() {        
        try {           
            //_.delay(function(){opts.func();}.bind(opts.context), 2000);
            setTimeout(function(){ return _.bind(opts.func, opts.context)(); }, 2000);
        } catch (e) {
            run(this.opts, this.interval);
        }       
    }
    run();      
};
```

Comment: I *suspect* that this line may do something different the second run: `!this.dbOpen && this.init();` ... Also not sure what `this.opts, this.interval` is referring to in the catch? Both seem `undefined`.

Comment: these are part of the original code I neglected to remove, but in fact this is the line that is faulty but not becuase it is undefined, it is, becuase this loses its context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything like the description. Also the description isn't clear: what does "if it [`func`] fails" mean? Does `func` throw an exception? Return `false`? Or what?

There is no code to check the return value from `func`, yet the example version of `func` returns `true`. What is the purpose of the `true` return value?

You have a try/catch block, which made me suspect you are talking about the `func` call throwing an exception. But this try/catch won't catch any exception that `func` throws!

That's because the try/catch is wrapping the `setTimeout` call. But `func` is not called from inside that try/catch block. It's called *later*, when the timeout fires, and the try/catch is no longer in effect at that time.

What is the `opts.success` function? It is never used.

Also, the code always takes a two-second delay before the first attempt to call `func`. Do you want that, or do you want the first call to be immediate and only take the delay if the call fails and you retry?

Here is a working example that does something like what you're talking about. I made the assumption that "fail" means "throw an exception", and that you don't want any delay on the initial `func` call.

To test the code I used a `func` function that runs a countdown and throws an exception each time and finally succeeds when the countdown reaches 0.

Run this with the debug console open so you can see the `console.log()` messages:

```
function Test() {
    this.countdown = 5;

    succeeder({
        func: function () {
            console.log(
                this.constructor.name,
                'countdown:',
                this.countdown
            );
            if( this.countdown-- ) {
                console.log( 'func throwing error' );
                throw new Error( 'fail' );
            }
            console.log( 'func success!' );
        },
        context: this,
        interval: 1000,
        success: function () { return true; }
    });
};

new Test;

function succeeder(opts) {
    var func = _.bind( opts.func, opts.context );
    function run() {
        try {           
            func();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout( run, opts.interval );
        }       
    }
    run();      
};
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer and code correction, really helpful.